# Metadata Loading Issue on ClickHouse Cluster Restart

Tags: clickhouse

We rely on the ClickHouse Altinity operator deployed on Kubernetes to manage our ClickHouse infrastructure. Our current ClickHouse setup comprises three shards with a single replica, housing various databases such as default, olap, olap_local, staging, and staging_local. The primary database is named `olap`.

Our typical approach to table creation involves first establishing a simple MergeTree table on local databases and subsequently creating a distributed table on another database. To illustrate, when creating a table like `users`, we execute the following commands:

```sql
CREATE TABLE olap_local.users ON CLUSTER 'cluster' (id Int32) ENGINE MergeTree;
CREATE TABLE olap.users ON CLUSTER 'cluster' AS olap_local.users ENGINE Distributed('cluster', 'olap_local', 'users');
```

However, upon cluster restarts, we encounter issues during the loading metadata phase. It's important to note that our ClickHouse cluster houses approximately 200 GB of data on each shard.

I initially suspected was related to ClickHouse's inability to load dependencies on the OLAP database. However, when attempting to reproduce the bug in the staging cluster, I observed successful dependency loading.

Now, my hypothesis is leaning towards the size of the database potentially causing the problem.

I'm reaching out to the community for insights, experiences, or solutions related to this issue.

Thank you for your time and support.